# Can't read cookie on some wordpress hosts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin that reads cookies using:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["status"])) {
   return true;
}
```

This code works fine when running on a website hosted on SiteGround. When I run on a website hosted on euroDNS it can never read the cookie, even thought I can see it in the browser debug tab.

Do some WordPress hosting providers disable the reading of cookies?

Comment: It would make very little sense for any type of web hoster, to somehow "disable" receiving of incoming cookies in general.

Comment: Chrome (and probably other browsers) has a great "show filtered out request cookies" that can troubleshoot this to determine why a specific cookie isn't being sent for a specific request. Also, if a host has a proxy such as Varnish in front of the site, sometimes they only allow certain cookies through for caching reasons, so you might want to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by adding the prefix `wordpress_` to the start of the cookie name. That seems to be required to allow the cookies to be passed all the way to my plugin on some hosting environments.